# German Employment Visa Complication

Tags: germany, foreign-employment

I have recently received and accepted a job offer with a German company in the field I hold a qualification in.

The job is unregulated in Germany (Sales Executive) and the salary is 45,000€ annually. The industry is niche and my qualification (recognised by the appropriate authority in Germany) sets me apart from other candidates, hence me getting the job.

Since submitting my employment visa application, the Federal Employment Agency have been hounding my employer about their motivations behind hiring a foreign worker versus those applicants within the country etc… I understand the requirement for them to ascertain that there are no ‘preferential’ EU/EEA Citizen candidates, however I am confused about how preferential is defined in this instance- as the employer has a clearly stated reason for not going ahead with said candidates (awarding the job based on merit).

Could this ‘stubbornness’ around the hiring of a citizen/resident result in my application being declined? If so,do I have any recourse?

Thank you!

Comment: yes, it can. Your resource is paying for an immigration lawyer in Germany to clarify the issue. It is not an easy question to resolve without a lawyer.